# Drupal Replacement Pattern for Entity Reference

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-rules

I have a Profile Type attached to a user. In there I have a Entity Reference Field of Program Manager. I have Live Events(content-type) that people can register for. I set up a Rule to Email the Program Manager every time someone registers.

My problem is I am trying to pull information from the Profile based on the the entity reference for the Program Manager.

I have the field printing out by using this pattern...

```
[registration:entity:field_program_manager]
```

However when I try to pull the first name, email of phone I can not get it to show up.

Does anyone have any ideas to share?
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was trying to solve for sending the email to the Author of the page but was having issues. So I created a new fields hoping it would be easier. In trying to solve for this I solved the original issue.

To print the Author of a node to an email through Rules actions us this.

```
[registration:entity:author]
```

So for first name it would be:

```
[registration:entity:author:profile-main:field_first_name]
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using entityform instead of a node and referencing the default user info (not the 'Main Profile' profile type), then you want to use something like

```
[entityform:field-staff-entity-ref:field-work-email]
```

In this case, 'field-staff-entity-ref' is the entity reference field in the entityform and 'field-work-email' is the field in the user's account settings.